# How can I create a LINQ statement where the table name (FROM) and column name (SELECT) is variable?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, webforms

In my programming task I've gone down a dark alley and wished I hadn't, but there is no turning back now.

I'm building up a SQL statement where the table name, column name and id value are retrieved from query string parameters i.e. `("SELECT [{0}] FROM [{1}] WHERE [Id] = {2};", c, t, id)`

But it isn't as bad as it looks, I'm protected:

- Only authenticated users (i.e. signed in users) can execute the `Page_Load`
- I'm checking that both the table and the column exists beforehand
  (using `GetSchema` etc.)
- I'm checking that the Id is an integer beforehand
- All my tables have Id columns
- The database connection is reasonably secure

The field value is expected to be of type NVARCHAR(4000) or NVARCHAR(MAX) so I'm avoiding `ExecuteScalar` and I'm trying out LINQ `ExecuteQuery` because I like LINQ. But I'm a bit out of my depth again.

I've got this far:

```
    Dim db As New MyDataContext

    Dim result = db.ExecuteQuery(Of ITable)("SELECT [{0}] FROM [{1}] WHERE [Id] = {2};", c, t, id)
```

- Is this the right way to go?
- How do I get first row and first column value?
- Is there a better alternative?

P.S. It's a SQL Server 2005 database

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If table name or column name contains a bracket, then it will pass the check (it exists), but result in invalid SQL. Use [`quotename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114(v=sql.90).aspx). Always.

Comment: Are you talking about square brackets or curly braces?

Comment: Square brackets, the outermost thing in your placeholders.

Comment: SELECT [Text] FROM [WebPage] WHERE [Id] = 2; I think this is valid 
T-SQL?

Comment: Yes, it is valid SQL. Now imagine the table is called `Web]Page`. It is 100% allowed.

Comment: Is this regarding SQL injection? Because none of my tables names contain a square bracket? Are you saying that `sqlConn.GetSchema("Tables", {Nothing, Nothing, "Web]Page"})` will work?

Comment: Yes, it will work provided table `Web]Page` exists. Or it can be `WebPage[1]`. Or something along the lines. The point is, the kind of substitution you are doing is not protecting you from anything. Always use `quotename` for object names (first collect the input, then call `quotename` for each item, then substitute the sanitized strings into the query). Even if it seems an overkill for your current data schema, it will make sure you don't have problems in future.

Comment: I would look into something like oData or .Net web API instead.

Comment: @GSerg Now I'm with you. But I think in my case that would only give me more protection against bad SQL and also future-proofing my code. Great tip anyhow!

Comment: You can use [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) or Scott Guthrie has a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) that talks about the Dynamic Query Library add on that seems interesting, but I haven't used the latter.

Comment: Don't see how the table name can be variable in any of the examples! Maybe if I learnt expressions trees then it would become obvious. But I'm not willing to learn something unless I can be sure it is what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server requires the tables ans columns to be statically known. You can't provide them using command parameters. You can't say

```
select * from @tableName
```

because the table name can't be a variable.

You need to build the SQL string with C# ensuring proper escaping of identifiers. Escaping works like this:

```
var escaped = "[" + rawUntrustedUserInput.Replace("]", "]]") + "]";
```

This is safe.

Comment: What is rawUntrustedUserInput? What about "]"?

Comment: "]" is the escape char. SELECT QUOTENAME(']') yields '[]]]'. The opening brance does not need to be escaped (was a bug in my code).

Comment: Yeah I so I just `String.Format("[{0}]", tableName.Replace("]", "]]"))` are you sure the first square bracket doesn't need to be escaped? Are you saying that SELECT * FROM [My[Table] is valid T-SQL?

Comment: Yes, just try it. Any string at all can be an identifier if it is properly escaped. Just like any string at all can be a C# string literal if escaped. The rules of the two languages allow for this.